# PHPUnit - service class is private, you cannot replace it

Tags: php, symfony, mocking, phpunit

In my PHPUnit test, I have I private class:

```
$fakePayStubViewManager = $this->prophesize(PayStubViewManager::class);
$this->client->getContainer()->set(PayStubViewManager::class, $fakePayStubViewManager->reveal());
```

The error I am getting:

> The "PayStubsCore\PayStubGeneratorBundle\Manager\PayStubViewManager" service is private, you cannot replace it.

`prophesize()` method is deprecated.

I was not able to find a proper way to replace the logic. I tried with stubs and also would need a substitute for the `reveal()` method as well.

Did anyone encountered a similar issue and can help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The symfony docs state:

> If you need to test private services that have been removed (those who are not used by any other services), you need to declare those private services as public in the config/services_test.yaml file.

*Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test*

They are describing services that are removed from the container, because they are not used. But the same can be applied for your use-case.

By default all services are considered private, you could convert them all to public in your `services_test.yml` or just convert a single service instead.